# Counting instances across ranges in columns

Tags: excel

I am creating a spreadsheet for my personal use. I need to count the number of times one column's values are equal to an adjacent column's.

Is there any way to do this in Excel without having to modify the formula every time a new row is added?

Answer (score 1):

If you have column A and B now, add column C:

```
    Column A   Column B   Column C
    1          2          =countif(B:B, A1)
    2          2          
    3          1
```

Then just copy the first value in column C, select the entire column C and paste :)

You will get:

```
Column C
1
2
0
```